# How to listen for a new record insert via C# in Azure tables

Tags: c#, azure, triggers, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I have found solution where I am able to listen for a new record insert in SQL Server / MySql, but from what I can see in the documentation, there is no option for setting up a trigger for Azure tables when an insert happens that would call a http method/api.

I have no option of changing Azure tables to something else, so my question is, is there an elegant way to listen through a C# console app for a record insert in Azure tables?

Comment: can you add a field to the table or does it have an existing createdon field?

Comment: We do have a createdon, indeed we can schedule a console app that will make the comparison based on it. I was thinking more, is it possible to send an event to azure service bus or call a http trigger so we are closer to "real time" but can't seem to find something other than manual lifting.

Answer (score -1):

A Logic App which runs periodically can read new records using the timestamp they were created.  That Logic App can do whatever you want with the records, put on Service Bus, call an api, anything a Logic App can do.  You can set the schedule duration for looking for new records to an interval that meets your needs.

You could do the same thing with C# code reading the Azure table but it seems to me it is simpler to have a Logic App do it.